# Avoid using this.Invoke(..) on an event handler in c# compact framework

Tags: c#, forms, events, thread-safety, compact-framework

I’m using a separate class that instantiates different barcode objects depending on the type of machine, which raise events once a barcode is read.

So to transmit it to the form, I also raise an UNIQUE event ‘myEvent’ that all my forms listens, but inside the form I have to use this.Invoke((Action) mymethod(argument)); to be able to update the components at the user interface, as long as the handler to myEvent is executed on another thread different from that of the form.

So I have this:

My class -> barcode.readed(..) is triggered, then from its handler, I Raise myEvent, that is captured on my Form, and from the handler for myEvent on my form, I execute the this.Invoke…

I know this is a somewhat standard procedure, but I’d like to get rid of that Invoke, and instead, calling directly to the myMethod(argument); function.

I think that this is related to make my class thread safe, but I don’t know how to implement that in my case.

In fact, if I use the original manufacturer barcode.readed() event from inside the form it does not need to call the invoke, as long as this is thread safe, but I don’t know how to mimic that, and I really need to wrap all the different barcode handlers inside a different project, for my forms to use only one ‘myEvent’ that returns the desired barcode, and thus, not repeating code.

Thanks in advance,

Roger Tranchez

Answer (score 2):

If you inherit your class from control (basically create a new custom control), you can handle events on the UI thread without using Invokes as the control (your barcode reader class) is part of the UI thread.

Comment: Great ! It worked, thanks: I've created a new custom control. Then, I had to cut the protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) from the designer to my custom control class, because if I didn't do that, I was not allowed to implement the destruction of my barcode readers inside my class. Finally, the creation of the custom control automatically creates the function OnPaint: As far as I understand, I can simply leave it as it is, as my control does not have any interface. Is it correct ?

Comment: Right, you do not need a Paint code if your 'control' does not paint anything.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using a worker thread for reading barcodes, to keep the UI responsive. And the barcode object just runs on whichever thread created it.

You can centralise event handling (to avoid repeating code) and read barcodes on a worker thread as follows:

- Wrap the barcode object inside a custom object/library MyBarcodeReader that exposes MyEvent.
- In the constructor for MyBarcodeReader, capture the current SynchronizationContext to a class field syncContext. This will be your UI's SynchronizationContext if your form constructs MyBarcodeReader.
- When you activate MyBarcodeReader (e.g. MyBarcodeReader.Execute), create the barcode object on a worker thread.
- When you need to raise MyEvent, call syncContext.Send (this will be on the worker thread), passing a delegate whose purpose is to raise MyEvent. syncContext.Send will synchronise to the UI thread (like Control.Invoke). The code below illustrates this.

---

```
public class MyBarcodeReader
{
    private readonly SynchronizationContext syncContext;

    // Handler for barcode object's Readed event.
    private void Barcode.Readed(Object sender, Event e)
    {
        // Block the worker thread to synchronize with the thread associated
        // with SynchronizationContext.
        syncContext.Send(SyncMyEvent, (Object)e);
    }

    // Raises MyEvent on the thread associated with SynchronizationContext,
    // usually a UI thread.
    private void SyncMyEvent(Object o)
    {
        if (MyEvent != null)
        {
            MyEvent((Event)o);
        }
    }

    // Constructor.
    public MyBarcodeReader()
    {
        syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    }
}
```

The approach here will block the worker thread (same as Control.Invoke) but not block the UI thread. If you have one or more forms that subscribe to MyEvent, they don't need to use Control.Invoke; they don't even need to know about the worker thread.

There are some excellent online references on SynchronizationContext, see [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31971/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-I) and [MSDN magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx).

Comment: Thanks ! I'm not explicitly using a working thread, I'm only instantiate the class that contains the native objects that raise events, and then I raise my own event from that class, that is captured in the form.

I'm working with Compact Framework 3.5, does not have the SynchronizationContext feature.

I've tried to use this [implementation](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2009/02/03/part-i-mimic-synchronizationcontext-behaviour-on-net-cf/)
But it didn't work as the example does not implement the .Current member. 

I think I'd need another approach...

Comment: If the example does not implement the .Current member why not use the class instance, as in `syncContext = SynchronizationContext`? Another option you could look at is http://nitoasync.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution [here](http://bansky.net/blog/2007/12/firing-thread-safe-events-in-compact-framework/): Basically it passes over the form control to the class constructor, and then, inside that class it uses the form.Invoke to fire the event from the form ui thread.

CLASS:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace ThreadTest
{
    public class WorkerClass
    {
        private Thread thr;

        // UI control for update
        public Control UIControl { get; set; }

        public delegate void StatusUpdate(DateTime dateTime, string message);
        public event StatusUpdate OnStatusUpdate;

        // Starts thread
        public void Start()
        {
            thr = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MainWorker));
            thr.Start();
        }

        // Main thread worker
        public void MainWorker()
        {
            int i = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                string message = string.Format("Value of i={0}", i++);
                FireStatusUpdate(DateTime.Now, message);

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        // Fire thread safe event
        private void FireStatusUpdate(DateTime dateTime, string message)
        {
            // UIControl is set and OnStatusUpdate has subscriber
            if (UIControl != null && OnStatusUpdate != null)
            {
                if (UIControl.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    UIControl.Invoke(new StatusUpdate(FireStatusUpdate), 
                                            new object[] { dateTime, message });
                    return;
                }

                OnStatusUpdate(dateTime, message);
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

FORM:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ThreadTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {        
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            WorkerClass worker = new WorkerClass();
            // add event handler
            worker.OnStatusUpdate += new WorkerClass.StatusUpdate(worker_OnStatusUpdate);
            // add UI control to invoke
            worker.UIControl = this;
            worker.Start();
        }

        void worker_OnStatusUpdate(DateTime dateTime, string message)
        {
            label1.Text = dateTime.ToLongTimeString();
            label1.Text += " " + message;
        }
}
```

In my case, I've changed the type of event, from StatusUpdate to

```
 EventHandler<MyEventArgs>
```

, being MyEventArgs this class:

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  public string MyString { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you !